# how to navigate from one page to another in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have two components. In first component I have one button. On click of button I want to navigate to another component or another page.

here is my code
http://codepen.io/naveennsit/pen/pymqPa?editors=1010

```
class App extends React.Component {
    handleClick(){
      alert('---');
    }

    render() {
        return <button onClick={this.handleClick}>hello</button>
    }
}

class Second extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <label>second component</label>
    }
}

React.render( <App /> , document.getElementById('app'))
```

Answer (score 63):

There are two approaches here, both fairly easy.

**Approach 1: Using React Router**

Make sure you have the route set up somewhere in your project already. It should contain this information at the very least: path and component. It should be defined something like this:

```
import YourComponent from "./path/of/your/component"; 

<Route path="/insert/your/path/here" component={YourComponent} />
```

Next, you want to update your `handleClick` function to use a `Link` from `react-router-dom` (may have to install this package if you don't already have it using `npm i react-router-dom`).

Delete this (your `handleClick` function you don't need it with `Link`):

```
handleClick(){
  alert('---');
}
    render() {
        return <button onClick={this.handleClick}>hello</button>
    }

}
```

Now change your render method to this:

```
    render() {
        return (
          <div>
            <Link to="/insert/your/path/here" className="btn btn-primary">hello</Link>
         </div>
       ); 
    }

}
```

Give `Link` the same classNames that you would your button so it's styled as a button and not an anchor tag.

Putting it all together.

//Wherever your router is with your routes

```
    import YourComponent from "./path/of/your/component";

    <Router>
      <Route exact path="/insert/your/path/here" component={YourComponent} />
    </Router>
```

//The component that has the handleClick function

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom"; 

class App extends Component {
  render() {
     return(
       <div>
         <Link to="/insert/your/path/here" className="btn btn-primary">hello</Link>
      </div>
     );
  }
}
```

**Approach 2: Using `window.open`**

Still make sure you have the route set up like above. The difference here is that you will not be using `Link` which means you will need your `handleClick` function. That will be the only thing that changes.

Change this:

```
handleClick(){
  alert('---');
}
```

to this:

```
handleClick(){
  window.open("/insert/your/path/here");
  //this opens in a new tab (believe that is what the owner of the question wanted if not you can do window.location.href = "/insert/your/path/here". 
}
```

That's it. If you want to make your paths dynamic, meaning they include variables like id's or names etc. See below.

**Dynamic Paths**

Dynamic paths can include names and id's or whatever variable you would like. You first have to adjust your route and then change your Link or locations accordingly.

Change the Route to this:

```
<Route path="/insert/your/path/here/:name" component={YourComponent} />
```

Notice the colon (:), this allows you to inject a string here via variable.

Update your Link to this:

```
<Link to={`/insert/your/path/here/${variableName}`}>hello</Link>
```

And if you are using `window.open` update it like so:

```
window.open(`/insert/your/path/here/${variableName}`);
```

A few things to point out here. You are using brackets after the equal sign because that tells React, hey I need to input a variable here. Next notice the back ticks ` this tells React that you are using a string literal which means hey I want you to interpret this as a string but first get the value of my variable in here and turn into a string for me. And the ${} allows you to place a variable so React can properly interpret it. So all together, react reads that line as: take the user to path "/insert/your/path/here/valueOfVariablName" then React checks the routes for that path and says hey we have something that is "/insert/your/path/here/:name" so :name must equal valueOfVariableName. Hope that makes a little sense. You can verify dynamic path's in your console. Log your props. You should see an object that contains location, history, etc.

You can also read more about React-Router [here](https://medium.com/@pshrmn/a-simple-react-router-v4-tutorial-7f23ff27adf). Raw link: https://medium.com/@pshrmn/a-simple-react-router-v4-tutorial-7f23ff27adf

If anyone has a better resource. Please feel free to edit my answer or leave a comment with it.

I hope this helps anyone who comes across this question. Btw you can pass state through the `Link` as well. Please post another question if you would like to know how to do that.

Comment: One thing worth mentioning: Using Link doesn't refresh the page, while using window.location.href does refresh the page. If you're all about the single-page-application, this is definitely something you need to consider.

Answer (score 33):

Below are the best ways to deal with react navigations

Using `useHistory()` from `react-router-dom`

```
import React from 'react';
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
function NavigationDemo() {
  const history = useHistory();
  const navigateTo = () => history.push('/componentURL');//eg.history.push('/login');

  return (
   <div>
   <button onClick={navigateTo} type="button" />
   </div>
  );
}
export default NavigationDemo;
```

Using `Link` from `react-router-dom`

```
import React from 'react';
 import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

  function NavigationDemo() {

  return (
   <div>
   <Link  to={{pathname: '/componentURL'}}>NavigateNow</Link>
   </div>
  );
}
export default NavigationDemo;
```

Using `Redirect` from `react-router`

```
  import { Redirect } from 'react-router';

   <Redirect to='/componentURL' />
```

Comment: This is so much cleaner but adds a dependency to react-router-com. But then again react-router does more then just route.

Answer (score 25):

**Updated Answer:**

*"react-router-dom": "^6.2.2",*

Instead of **useHistory()**, now **useNavigate()** is exported from 'react-router-dom' to deal with all such navigations.

```
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom"
```

To redirect:

```
const navigate = useNavigate()

const onClickHandler = () => navigate(`/product/123`)
```

Answer (score 8):

If you want to build a single app I'd suggest using [React Router](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router). Otherwise you could just use plain Javascript:

```
window.location = 'newUrl';
```

Comment: I need to use React Router ..could you please tell me how to use this ?

Comment: Read the docs and check the examples. If you have a specific question create a new question here.

Comment: I added router js in my code pen where I will write configuration of router

Comment: I added an answer that goes over how to do it using the router.

Answer (score 1):

We shuold use struct like bellow

```
import history from 'services/History'
import { Router , Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";


class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router history={history} >
        <div className="root">
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/" component={MainPage} exact />
            <Route path="/dashboard" component={DashBoard} exact />
            <Route path="/docs" component={Docs} exact />
            <Route component={ErrorPage} />
          </Switch>

        </div>
      </Router >
    );
  }
}
```

with History.js is

```
// google analytics
import ReactGA from 'react-ga';
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';

ReactGA.initialize('UA-156453259-1');
ReactGA.pageview(window.location.pathname);


const history = createHistory();
history.listen((location) => {
  ReactGA.set({
    page: location.pathname,
  });
  ReactGA.pageview(location.pathname);
});

export default history;
```

Answer (score 0):

We use Link to navigate around to different routes that are hosted or being routed by react-router.

```
class App extends React.Component {
    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                <BrowserRouter>
                    <div>
                    <Route path="/"  component={Landing} exact />
                    <Route path="/surveys" component={Dashboard}/>
                    </div>
                </BrowserRouter>

            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

for those two components above you can use Link.

```
<Link to="/surveys">go to my surveys</Link>
```

However, anchor tags are used to navigate to completely different HTML documents. for example for google oauth, if you wanna log in the user, you have to navigate to a different url, when a user clicks on the "Login with Google" button.

```
<a href="/auth/google">Login with Google</a>
```