# How to redirect to another page on button click in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-router, reactjs.net

I want to create a basic web application using react. I have implemented creating buttons. I want to redirect to another page on button click. Below is my App.js code

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
        <p>
          <buttontoolbar>
            <button const path = '/Components'> Click Me </button>
          </buttontoolbar>
        </p>
     </header>
    </div>

  );
}

export default App;
```

When i click on 'click me' button it should redirect to Components.js. Below is the code for Components.js

```
import React from "react"

function app(){
 return(
  <p>
  Welcome to the world. 
  </p>
 )
}

export default app
```

Long back i have done these king of things in ASP.NET. there i have used `Response.redirect` to redirect pages which is so simple. As I am new to React, i know nothing about this. Is there anything like that in React?

Comment: The usual solution for this is to use React Router.

Just follow the [basic example](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/basic), you should be good to go.

Comment: Since one of your tags is `react-router` I assume you are looking for a solution involving it? Do you already have it set up?

Comment: Hi pierr V and Tom thank you for the reply. Pierre i have tried the example in link. Creating a link an d redirecting is coming. but when i try to create a button and redirect it am not getting it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically React does not have "pages". The idea is more to "show" or "hide" components, this gives the user a page/view impression.

The easiest way to achieve routing in React is to use a declarative router library like [react router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start) especially for more complex apps.

Here is an example without react router to understand the basic concept:

```js
const ViewOne = ({onClick}) => (
  <div>
    View 1 <br />
    <button onClick={() => onClick("view2")}>Go to view 2</button>
  </div>
);

const ViewTwo = ({onClick}) => (
  <div>
    View 2 <br />
    <button onClick={() => onClick("view1")}>Go to view 1</button>
  </div>
);



const App = () => {
  
  const [currentView, setCurrentView] = React.useState("view1");
  
  return (
      <div>
        {
          currentView === "view1" ? 
          <ViewOne onClick={page => setCurrentView(page)} /> : 
          <ViewTwo onClick={page => setCurrentView(page)} />
       }
      </div>
  );
};

const domContainer = document.querySelector('#my-app');
ReactDOM.render(<App />, domContainer);
```

```html
<div id="my-app"></div>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

try `Link` component of `react-router-dom`  and pass `to` as a path to it wherever you want to redirect on onClick.

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
```

and Eg.

```
<Link to={'/Components'}>
  <button > Click Me </button>
</Link>
```

```js
const {Link, BrowserRouter} = window.ReactRouterDOM
function App(){
  return (
  <BrowserRouter>
      <button><Link to='/abc' target='_blank'> Click Me  </Link></button>
   
    </BrowserRouter>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById("root"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-router-dom/umd/react-router-dom.min.js"></script>

<body><div id="root"></div></body>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use **react-router-dom** package to define **routing** and then use one of below mentioned ways on onClick event of button.

1. `this.props.history.push("componentpath")`.
2. browserHistory object (in **react-router** package).

Please refer this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37295377/how-to-navigate-from-one-page-to-another-in-react-js)

Comment: Hi Sandeep, I have tried the methods in the link. i am getting this error.             
Failed to compile
./src/App.js
  Line 39:  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ";"


> 39 | hello() {
     |         ^
  40 |   alert('you clicked on me');
  41 |   return (
  42 |     <div>

Comment: it must be syntactical error, i would help only if i get to see new code.

Comment: here is the link to the code snapshot https://drive.google.com/open?id=1i-4VjSYwbWX6zcGlpdOUttyI0XH2cPp-