# How to navigate in reactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-navigation

I want to navigate from one page to another in ReactJS I am using history.push but it gives me an error that
`TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push') at Login.jsx:65 at async loginHandel (Login.jsx:51)`

This is my App.js code

```
import React from "react";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import Login from "./components/Login";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Login />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

and this is my login.jsx function code

```
  const loginHandel = async () => {
    setLoading(true);
    const data = await axios
      .get(
        `http://116.202.231.219:8069/Restaurant/Login_Updated?Cont4=${email}&Pswd=${password}`
      )
      .then((res) => {
        //check the res if its getting the correct data or not?
        //restructure accordingly
        console.log(res);
        const persons = res;
        if (persons.status === 200) {
          //perform any thing here
          alert("It is working");
          // setUser(persons);
          setLoading(false);
          history.push("/dashboard");
          // window.open("./Dashboard.jsx")
          
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        //handel your error
        console.log(err);
        alert("User email and passwoed mismatched!");
        // setLoading(false);
      });
  };
```

I want that after the API success it should navigate me to the dashboard page but it does not and it gives the alert of it is working and also gives the alert of    User email and passwoed mismatched I would really appreciate it if any of you could help me sort this problem

Comment: Can you make a simple search before make ask? [check this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37295377/how-to-navigate-from-one-page-to-another-in-react-js)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Couple of things you need to have:

1. Router for your base ([Check here](https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start) for better understanding)

```
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route} from 'react-router-dom'

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
         <Switch>
           <Route path='/' component={/* Import and use your component */} />
         </Switch>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}
```

2. Use the `useHistory` hook to access `history.push` (This will be true for the components who are rendered under `<Router>`)

```
import {useHistory} from 'react-router-dom'

const YourFunctionComponent = props => {

  const history = useHistory()
  
  const letsChangeLocation = () => history.push('/wherever')
}
```

Comment: I used this code but it still does not go to the next page though the URL gets changed but the page is still the same,  I am using the code as same as you have written here.

Comment: Did you include the `path` you are trying to go as a `<Route path=...`?

Comment: Here is  a [working codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-pateu-ls8uj?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 0):

you need to import useHistory in your component. then use it to navigate.

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

// in component

const history = useHistory();
history.push('/url')
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Define Routes in main base file.
2. use [useHistory](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/usehistory) for react router version 5

   ```
   import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

   function HomeButton() {
     let history = useHistory();

     function handleClick() {
       history.push("/home");
     }

     return (
       <button type="button" onClick={handleClick}>
         Go home
       </button>
     );
   }
   ```

   use [useNavigate](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#usenavigate), for react router version 6

   ```
   import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

   function SignupForm() {
     let navigate = useNavigate();

     async function handleSubmit(event) {
       event.preventDefault();
       await submitForm(event.target);
       navigate("../success", { replace: true });
     }

     return <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>{/* ... */}</form>;
   }
   ```