# How to do routing in react by clicking a button in class component?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I was having a button in a react **class component** as following

```
 <Link to="display">
    <button onClick={this.nextBtn} className="nextBtn">
        Submit
    </button>
 </Link>
```

By clicking the button, I need to route it to another component called `<Display />` using the  function `nextBtn = () => {}`.

I saw that in the function component it can be by `useHistory` but in the class component, I don't know how to do it.

Comment: you can do that on the body of this.nextBtn function, so remove Link wrapper and import Router and Router.push('/newRoute')

Comment: Why can't the `Link` component do its job and link to the path rendering the `Display` component? All the answers below don't ask this basic question, and assume the code in your snippet has access to the route props of the nearest router. Can you provide a more comprehensive and complete code example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use `withRouter` from `import { withRouter } from "react-router";` and inject your component. You can get `history` as a props and use `history.push()` for navigate route.

**Example:**

```
import React from "react";
import { withRouter } from "react-router";

class ShowTheLocation extends React.Component {
  nextBtn = () => {
    const { history } = this.props;

    history.push("/display");
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Link to="display">
        <button onClick={this.nextBtn} className="nextBtn">
          Submit
        </button>
      </Link>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(ShowTheLocation);
```

Comment: It shows "withRouter' (imported as 'withRouter') was not found in 'react-router".. Using react-router-dom v6.2.1

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this. It's works for me

```
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router';
    class MyClass extends Component {
        nextBtn = () => {
           browserHistory.push('/display');
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can route to another page using several methods.
First, in your case, you are using a Link. But your route name passing is wrong. You have to pass the route name in front like this:

```
        <Link to={'/display'}> 
        // display should be a routes name
         <button className="nextBtn">
         Submit
         </button>
         </Link>
```

https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Link.

You can read more about it here:

Secocnd method: 
Use react-router-dom package to define the routing and then use one of below mentioned ways on onClick event of button.

```
  1. this.props.history.push("componentpath").
  2. browserHistory object (in react-router package).
```

Also check this question solutions... [how to navigate from one page to another in react js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37295377/how-to-navigate-from-one-page-to-another-in-react-js)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you`re using a library for routing like react-router.

You want to get access to the history object from react-router. React router offers so called higher order functions which have access to the history and inject it into your class-component. Then inside of your component your have access to it via this.props.history.

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

//JS-Example
class YourJSComponent extends Component {

 /**
 * Since the class gets exported wrapped in withrouter(YourComponent), history is now in the props.
 */

anyRedirectMethod = () => {
 this.props.history.push("/yourRoute")
}
 

 render(

   return(
    <Link to="display">
     <button onClick={this.anyRedirectMethod} className="nextBtn">
      Submit
     </button>
    </Link>
   )

 )
}

export default withRouter(YourJSComponent);
```